# C++ template in header file, error in implementation-file *.cc "error: expected a class or namespace"

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I've specified a header file like this:

**04-Templates_foo.h:**

```
template <typename T>

class foo {
    T x, y;
    T getX(void);
    void setX(T x);
};
```

And an implementation like this:

**04-Templates_foo.cc:**

```
#include "04-Templates_foo.h"

template <typename T>
T foo::getX(void) {
    return this->x;
}

void foo::setX(T x) {
    this->x = x;
}
```

My main routine:

**04-Templates.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "04-Templates_foo.cc"

int main (void) {
    // Do nothing because it doesn't even compile...
}
```

**Compiling this code returns this error:**

```
In file included from 04-Templates.cc:2:
./04-Templates_foo.cc:4:3: error: expected a class or namespace
T foo::getX(void) {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

I can't imagine what the problem is. Why can't I specify the function foo::getX? It's a class name, although the compiler said it is expecting a class and didn't find one :-/

If it may be important. I'm compiling this on a MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2012 with Mavericks.
I used this compile-command:

```
g++ -o 04-Templates 04-Templates.cc
```

Suggestions for a better title are welcome ;)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal no, it is OK in this case. It is template code, so it has to be visible to `main`. It is unconventional, but it should work with the compilation line shown (and the fix suggested in Joachim's answer.)

Comment: @juanchopanza yes sorry forgot about the template code and compilation line.

Comment: Do **not** call a header file `.cc`. `.cc` is reserved by convention for implementation files (better: use `.cpp`) – lots of tool chains will interpret it that way. In case that isn’t clear: a header file is a file you `#include` in your code, and you must never include source files.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I did not call the header file *.cc. It is named: 04-Templates_foo.h as you can see in the Question. But thanks for the advice  anyway.

Comment: @tmuecksch No. `04-Templates_foo.cc` is *also* used as a header file in your code: you `#include` it. Or, put differently: you *must not* `#include` non-header files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the definition of `foo::getX` (and `setX` as well), what *kind* of `foo`?

Because it's a template class, you have to specify that, like

```
template<typename T>
T foo<T>::getX(void) { ... }
```

---

You also have to tell the compiler that member functions are templates *for each function in a templated class*. So you have to do it for `setX` as well:

```
template<typename T>
void foo<T>::setX(T x) { ... }
```

Comment: This works so far for the function getX. But it does not for `void foo<T>::setX(T x){ ... }`. Error: "use of undeclared identifier 'T'"

Comment: @tmuecksch Because you forgot the `template` part.

Comment: I got it working by repeatedly declaring the typename by template<typename T>. Could you add this to your solution? So I can mark it as accepted.